# Powershell copy script with condition check

Tags: powershell, copy

Our requirement is to copy files from source to the destination folder.

The clause is during the first run of the script everything should be copied but in the subsequent runs it should copy only those files which have not been copied till yet and are new ones.

The issue is from the destination folder we have a script that works on the files and remove them once executed. So we dont want duplicate files from source copied to destination.

Example

```
source-> abc.txt,def.xt
```

after 1strun

```
dest->abc.txt,def.txt
```

subsequent runs

```
source->abc.txt,def.xt, ghi.txt

dest->abc.txt,def.xt, ghi.txt
```

Now when another script has worked on dest folder and removed `abc.txt` and `ghi.txt` then the logic should be

```
source->abc.txt,def.xt, ghi.txt,jkl.txt
```

Now when the script runs it should only copy the new files

```
dest->ghi.txt, jkl.txt
```

I was thinking if we can log the output after the script is run for the first time to a txt file and then put a condition to check in that log file if the text file is there  before copying anything from the source folder to the destination .

Hope was able to explain.

Thx

Comment: Use [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). It was made for this kind of task.

Comment: I tried something like this with robocopy,$src_folder="C:\Users\Desktop\Test"
$dest_folder="C:\Users\Desktop\Test1"

Robocopy $src_folder $dest_folder /m

IF ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
{
Write-host copying complted successfully
}
Else
{
Write-host Error Copying File
}
But the problem is it is copying everything . I want the content that is in source folder but has never been copied to dest folder

Comment: As [documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), the option `/m` copies all source files where the `archive` attribute is set. If you want to exclude files that already exist in the destination use `/xx` (exclude extra files). If you want to exclude files that have been copied to the destination at any point in the past, regardless of whether or not they still exist in the destination, you will indeed have to use a custom script and a copy history.

Comment: @ansgar that's correct and exactly what we intend to do..so need help in creating that custom script..if you can guide me onto that..i tried appying the logic but not very much familiar with the windows powerdhell commandlets..here is my test script:

Comment: Somehow not able to paste in the entire script..will post it in pieces

Comment: $src = "C:\Test\"
$dest = "C:\Test1\"

# Getting Files/Folders from Source and Destination
$SrcEntries = Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse
$DesEntries = Get-ChildItem $dest -Recurse

# Parsing the folders and Files from Collections
$SrcFiles = $SrcEntries | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer}
$DesFiles = $DesEntries | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer}

$LogFile = Get-Content -Path "C:\Test\Log.txt"

Comment: foreach ($file in $SrcFiles)
{
 if ($DesFiles -eq "")
 {
 Write-Host "This is your first run. Copying all the files from the source to the destination"
 $firstcopy = Copy-Item $src $dest 
 #Append the output to log file
 $firstcopy | Out-File $LogFile -Append
 }
else
{
if ($LogFile -contains $file)
 {Write-Host "This file was already copied since presnt at $LogFile"}
else
 {Write-Host "New file found. Copying.."
 Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $dest}
}

}

Answer (score 0):

You could copy those files which are not in your history like this:

```
$sourceFolder = "..."
$destFolder   = "..."
$historyFile  = "history.txt"

$recurse = $false

$history = Get-Content $historyFile

Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder -Recurse:$recurse | ? {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $history -notcontains $_.FullName
} | % {
  Copy-Item $_.FullName $destFolder
  $_.FullName >> $historyFile
}
```

The line `$_.FullName >> $historyFile` appends the copied files to the history file.